# How to use Anonyfox/meteor-scrape with meteor-react

Tags: reactjs, meteor, web-scraping

Anonyfox/meteor-scrape:
https://github.com/Anonyfox/meteor-scrape

layout from https://github.com/AdamBrodzinski/meteor-react-boilerplate

i don't know how to use Anonyfox/meteor-scrape witg meteor-react.

Comment: Could you try `websiteData = Scrape.website("http://example.com/article");`?

Comment: new issue : https://s27.postimg.org/i0ivx2977/Screenshot_from_2017_01_04_00_10_13.png

Comment: Put `<div>{websiteData}</div>` right after the `h1`, you always have to wrap your elements in a parent container element. Could you edit your question to include that code? I can prepare an answer for you then.

Comment: whem i use this `websiteData = Scrape.website("http://example.com/article");`  now i dont get any error on terminal but my page is gone. i dont know how to use this, can you example for me.
ps.sorry for my english skill

Comment: I just realized that this package does not work on the client (browser) but needs to run in your server code.

Answer (score 0):

This package hasn't been updated in 2 years, and the author warns this:

> Scraping is a game of catch-22, and everything may break everytime.

If you look at the fork history on github

https://github.com/Anonyfox/meteor-scrape/network

You will see that other users have forked the repo, but there is nothing of note. The original author did start a fork for a rewrite, but that was in May 2015.

Unless you are willing to work this out the hard way by cloning and debugging the code, it's probably a dead end for you.

There are plenty of well supported tools for web scraping around, such as Casper, Scrapy and others.